# When i hover over the button i want new image to describe that button, but it's blinking

Tags: html, css, hover

I want that when I hover over the button to keep the button on its place and show a little describe box below. There's no picture in demo, so you can't see exactly what I am talking about.
Here's also a pic how it should look like.
[image]

Demo: http://jsbin.com/UXAleHi/1

### CSS:

```
nav .ona  a{
   width: 151px;
   height: 70px;
   line-height: 76px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 350px;
}

nav .ona a:hover{
   width: 293px;
   height: 62px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 70px;
   left: 257px;
   background-image: url("Images/onama.png");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   display: block;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add the code you're working on to the question, so somebody can help to improve it.

Comment: There's the code in jsbin link. Just click edit in jsbin and you'll get both html and css code. Please...

Comment: its because you change the position of the element when you hover, thus making it not hover. Then it goes back to hovering and it continues. You got yourself some recursion.

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but what I don't know is how to fix it, how to keep the button on the same place, and plus to get the description box below.

Comment: In general it's best to include relevant information, particularly the code, in the question itself.  Linking to something like jsbin is useful as a supporting resource, but if that link ever goes stale then the question will no longer have any meaningful information.  In general, it's best to present all relevant information in the question instead of asking people to go find it for themselves.

Comment: @user1938671 is right. And for the second part: You could add another elment inside the link and toggle it on hover, like: `<a>Link <span>Extra information</span></a>`. And the CSS could be: `a > span { display: none; }; a:hover > span { display: block; }`.

Comment: Can you help me more by editing my live demo, so I can exactly understand what you meant?

Comment: I created a simpler test case on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wVbXg/). Hope it helps.

Comment: Will it work with background-image aswell?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes of course it will, here's [another demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xer8m/).

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna try it.

Comment: I've made it. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments:

Don't re-size and don't set another position on the link element itself when hovering. This will keep it in the same place. I've created a simplified demo of your code with an example, how you can show another content while hovering:

**HTML**

```
<div class="ona">
    <a href="onama.html">
        O NAMA
        <span>Some more infos</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.ona  a {
    width: 150px;
    line-height: 75px;
    position: absolute;
}

.ona  a:hover {
    background: transparent url(http://lorempixel.com/150/75) no-repeat 0 0;
}

.ona a > span {
    display: none;
}

.ona a:hover > span {
    display: block;
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/xer8m/)